# Macro starts only in active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I'm new in excel VBA. I found a macro on the internet that solved my problem very good. But a little problem remains that this macro runs on the active sheet only. I want to run it on my specified sheet (for example sheet1). I put this macro here and please guide me to solve this problem.

```
Sub SelectByValue(Rng1 As Range, TargetValue As String)

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim Cell As Object

    'Check every cell in the range for matching criteria.

    For Each Cell In Rng1
        If Cell.Value > TargetValue Then
            If MyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set MyRange = Range(Cell.Address)
                Else
                Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, Range(Cell.Address))
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Select the new range of only matching criteria

 MyRange.Select


End Sub

Sub CallSelectByValue()

    'Call the macro and pass all the required variables to it.
    Call SelectByValue(Range("A1:D500"), "")

End Sub
```

Comment: You are working with several so-called implicit references to the `ActiveSheet`. For example: `Set MyRange = Range(Cell.Address)`. You need to preceed `Range(...)` by an `Explicit` sheet reference. Otherwise `VBA` will automatically refer to the `ActiveSheet`. Best to set a `Worksheet` variable. > `Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. Then use that in your references > `ws.Range(...)`

Comment: Why are using ">" with a string?

Comment: @JvdV Thank for your reply. I use your solution in my macro but it works only when sheet1 is active. If we on other sheets Run time error appears.

Comment: Remove `MyRange.Select` statement along side @JvdV suggestion. You don't need things like `Select` or `Activate` in VBA (unless on very rare occasions.. and this isn't one of them)

Comment: @Zac Thanks for reply. your suggestion doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try building a sheet selection into the `Sub CallSelectByValue()` perhaps?

I'm not exactly a pro yet myself, but here's a coupla suggestions:

**1. Define the sheet in the `CallSelectByValue` Sub**
(Copied your code and edited it:)

```
Sub CallSelectByValue()

Dim Sheet as WorkSheet
Set Sheet = Sheets("Sheet1") 'insert relevant sheet name

'Call the macro as before, but include the sheet reference in the range
Call SelectByValue(Sheet.Range("A1:D500"), "")

'Update after comments;
Sheet.Activate

End Sub
```

**2. Input the desired sheet each time (when using the sub repetitively on different sheets)**

```
Sub CallSelectByValue()

    'Find out what sheet to refer to
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    FindSheetName:
    SheetName = InputBox("Please enter the name of the sheet you'd like it to refer to", "Sheet Selection")

'Check the typed value is actually a sheet name
    If IsEmpty(Sheets(SheetName)) Then
        MsgBox "That sheet couldn't be found. Try again", vbOkOnly+vbCritical, "Sheet not found"
        GoTo FindSheetName 'loops you back to re-try typing it in
    Else
'If it matches up, assign that value to the Sheet variable
        Sheet = Sheets(SheetName)
    End If


'Update after comments;
Sheet.Activate

    'Call the macro and pass all the required variables to it, including the sheet reference
    Call SelectByValue(Sheet.Range("A1:D500"), "")

End Sub
```

Try those and let me know if they work.

Comment: Thank you Spencer Barnes for taking time and editing my code. Nothing of your suggestion work and still, this code is working in the active sheet only

Comment: haha - no problem, but evidently it wasn't much use!! What is your problem, do you need to use this in the non-active sheet? Would it matter to activate the new sheet every time? (If not, you could just put `Sheet.Activate` in either of my suggestions before calling the other sub, I think? I've edited it into my answer)

Comment: One other suggestion: have both the sheet and the VBA editor showing side-by side, put your cursor at the start of the macro (as if to type) and hit F8 key repeatedly. It will go through the macro step-by-step, and you'll be able to see exactly at which point things start going wrong - tends to help a lot in exactly identifying a problem.

Comment: Thanks again Spencer Barnes
Let me tell you the complete scenario
I want to select cells that aren't blank and copy them from one worksheet (inactive sheet) to another worksheet (may be active or not) (some cells get their value from IFERROR and their values = "" , and  I don't want to select them). This macro works very well to select the cells I want. My problem is, the macro works only on an active sheet and I can't find a solution for this.

Comment: The Copy and paste action isn't in your macro is it? Is it a part of the macro (or different sub) that you haven't included (presumably after `MyRange.Select`), or are you doing it more manually?

Comment: No. copy and paste action isn't in my macro. After solving the macro problem, I add it.

Comment: Ok - so I presume there's nothing wrong with having the code activate the copy-from sheet then? Have you tried the above code since I added that line?